# Sorting a Future List in Flutter

Tags: flutter, sorting, mobile, flutter-layout

I've been looking for a solution to sort a list (ascending and descending) `On Button Press` inside of a `FutureBuilder`, that is a `Future<List>`, but can't seem to understand how to define it as a List and then sort it on a button press. So I call the API, the API returns some dummy value, it's gets built in the Future Builder and in a `ListView.builder`, now I want sort the list by id (or by any type for that matter) but the method is not working because the list is null. The code:

API Call for the dummy data:

```
Future<List<Post>> fetchPosts() async {
  List<Post> posts = [];
  final response = await http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    var postsJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
    for (int i = 0; i < postsJson.length; i++) {
      posts.add(Post.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)[i]));
    }
    return posts;
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load posts');
  }
}
```

The Future Builder:

```
 List<Post> posts = []; /// if a define it like this, the value is always null
 Future<List<Post>> futurePosts;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futurePosts = fetchPosts();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              MaterialButton(color: Colors.grey, onPressed: (){
// here I am setting set to compare the values of all IDs so it can be sorted ascending and descending by number of ID every time I press the button
                setState(() {
                  posts.sort((a, b) => a.id.compareTo(b.id));
                });
              },),
              Container(
                height: 1000,
                child: FutureBuilder<List<Post>>(
                  future: futurePosts,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      return ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Text('${snapshot.data[index].id}')
                        },
                      );
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                    }
                    return Container();
                  },
                ),
```

But it seems my understanding and code is not working for me at this point. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: seems you need a `StreamBuilder` instead of `FutureBuilder` as you show your data multiple times, in order to trigger the `builder:` property callback you most likely would need a `StreamController.add` method

Comment: Ok, maybe you have a point, but does the sort method stays the same? That it is my question here, sorting, I can try with `StreamBuilder`...

Comment: Thanks mate, but `The method 'sort' isn't defined for the type 'Future'.`, since I'm calling an API, it s a Future<List<Post>> and not a List<Post>, what's the workaround that?

Comment: where you call `sort`? you need to call it on `posts` class field

Comment: When I call the API in `initState()`, since it is a Future<List<Post>> I have to define it like that `Future<List<Post>> list;` so in the button where I want to sort, I get `The method 'sort' isn't defined for the type 'Future'.`

Comment: `Future<List<Posts>> list;
  var ctrl = StreamController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    list = fetchPosts();
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () => list).then(ctrl.add);
  }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230793/discussion-between-grandmagus-and-pskink).

Comment: as you can see `fetchPosts` is `async` method but its return value is not used at all

Comment: Yeah, I see that mate, thanks a lot! Now the question is, how should I implement it on ONE button, should I use a boolean value or not? I actually was close to the solution, but you left the chat, but thanks a lot again!

Comment: ONE button? i think you could use `Switch` class, the docs say:
*"A material design switch.

Used to toggle the on/off state of a single setting."* - you can also use `Checkbox` class

Comment: Yeah, like a toggle button with the sort function, sort descending and ascending on single click. I will try with the Switch and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

You can move your  `posts.sort((a, b) => a.id.compareTo(b.id));` inside your Future function, before returning `posts`. And change the setState, to change the state of a boolean, which sorts or not.

You can change  like this:

```
//define a boolen
bool _isSorted =false;


Future<List<Post>> fetchPosts(bool sortORnot) async {
  List<Post> posts = [];
  final response = await http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    var postsJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
    for (int i = 0; i < postsJson.length; i++) {
      posts.add(Post.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)[i]));
    }
    if (sortORnot) {posts.sort((a, b) => a.id.compareTo(b.id));}// this will sort only if you wanted your list sorted.
    return posts;
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load posts');
  }
}
```

Change your `FutureBuilder` to this:

```
FutureBuilder<List<Post>>(
 future:_isSorted? fetchPosts(true):fetchPosts(false),
 builder: (context, snapshot) {
```

and `setState` to this:

```
 setState(() {
  _isSorted = !_isSorted; //this flips the value whenever you press it.
  });
```

Now, in your future builder, you should get the posts sorted, can you try this?

Comment: I've tried it, but it's not working, when I print out the `_isSorted` it does change to true and false, but the list stays the same, it is not sorting by ID value.

Comment: whenever I click the button, sometimes it calls in the API and sometimes it doesn't: `I/flutter ( 5048): outside the builder: false
I/flutter ( 5048): in the api: true
I/flutter ( 5048): outside the builder: true
I/flutter ( 5048): outside the builder: false
I/flutter ( 5048): in the api: true`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, I think, should work:

```
List<Post> posts;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  fetchPosts().then((items) {
    setState(() {
      posts = items;
    });
  });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    body: SafeArea(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child: Column(children: [
          MaterialButton(
            color: Colors.grey,
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                if (posts != null) {
                    posts = posts.toList();
                    posts.sort((a, b) => a.id.compareTo(b.id));
                }
              });
            },
          ),
          Container(
            height: 1000,
            child: (posts != null)
                ? ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: posts.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Text('${posts[index].id}');
                    },
                  )
                : Container(),
          )
        ]),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Your `posts` field is always empty because you never assign data to that field. And this is the main problem. Try it out.

Comment: The problem is that I have a `FutureBuilder` so if I set `future: posts`, it returns `The argument type 'List<Post>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<List<Posts>>'.`, so I'm right at the beginning.. Thanks tho!

Comment: Don't use `FutureBuilder` here.

Comment: Even without the `FutureBuilder` it is not working..

Comment: The `posts` is not empty but nothing is changing in the list...

Comment: I've updated the post. Maybe that would work for you?